# Good substitutes for Ross's book on Probability Models

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, online-resources

I was wondering if there are any **FREE** good alternatives to [Sheldon Ross's Probability Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123756863) which are more succinct?

Are there any free online resources (websites/PDFs/course notes) which cover more or less the same material?

I am looking for a quick (review)/(filling of knowledge gaps) and therefore would appreciate brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this one from Oliver Knill's page at Harvard:
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math144_1994/probability.pdf